# Mondrian database with wide time range

Tags: mysql, pentaho, mondrian

I have a task that requires me to use historical data from at least 5 years, to create a decision making model. Currently I'm using MySQL Foodmart database for mondrian, however it only covers one year. 
I tried to look for some alternative database with wider time range, but with no luck.

Does anyone know of any alternative db that I could use?

Comment: Why does it only cover 1 year?

Comment: Apparently, data in foodmart comes entirely from 1997, so the best I can do is, get data from 12 months.

Comment: Are you trying to a) test the functionality of Pentaho with some historical data spannign more than one year or b) to do real functional analysis on this datamart because it represents restricted real-life data?

Comment: b. I need to get five years (or more) sales and employee costs data to my Java application, aproximate it to a continous function and run it through my algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of datasets out there freely available to use. You can search for AdventureWorks, or the standard TPC-DS dataset.

For a quick start, I suggest you [buy the Mondrian book](http://www.manning.com/back/) and [download its VM](http://mondrianinaction.nicholasgoodman.com/MondrianInAction_11-APR-2013.ova), which contains everything already installed along with the AdventureWorks dataset and a schema for mondrian.